# How to build a generic map that could hold various data types as values whose type is known only during runtime?

Tags: java, generics

Some background: I'm modifying a class for an object that needs to hold properties which are added to it during runtime by the user. There is a list of property definitions that I've built in which each element contains a name for the property (unique) and its type (Stored in a String).

For an Example: "Name", "String" or "Year","int"

The challenge I'm facing now is translating this list to a map in which the name of the property is the key and the value variable type depends on what the user described. This map would hold the actual content of the properties described in the list (The content would be entered by the user on a later stage).

What would be the best way to deal with building this map using generics?

Comment: Take a look at this article http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html. You can use similar approach to build your version of type safe `Favorites` map.

Comment: Generics are a compile time feature.  They won't help you (much) for runtime checking if you don't know the types at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a [java.util.Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) - that's exactly what it was designed for.

It has other convenience methods, like loading from a file, dumping to XML, and other things you would probably find very useful.

And while technically it extends `Hashtable<Object,Object>` that's mostly for backwards compatibility. The methods on it indicate the expected usage will be `String` inputs.